# O Site fica em desacordo no responsivo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css3

Bem, dentro do corpo, coloquei duas boxs, col-md-6, com borda de 1px, porém uma ficava junto da outra, e não era pra ficar, aí coloquei um margin-left de 28px, nas duas boxs do meu lado esquerdo da tela, ou seja, segundo e quarto. Aí separou, as do canto esquerdo foram pro limite do Container, e o meio não estava mais junto, como na imagem: http://prntscr.com/7w66t1 
Mas, quando diminui para ver como ficar no responsivo, o segundo e o quarto não estavam responsivos, devido ao margin-left, segue o print das pordas, que deveriam estar na mesma margem, 0, http://prntscr.com/7w67e1, essa box do meio, que mostra o conteúdo e a ultima, ambas do lado esquerdo que estão em desacordo, A questão é: Como uso @media pra quando tiver numa dimensão, por exemplo: width: 600px, a margin-left não existir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de colocar o border no no elemento com col-md-6, cria outro dentro.
Ex:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div style="border:1px solid #cor;">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Ou

```
@media(max-width:600px) {
  .col-md-6 {margin-left:0;}
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, o media resolveu bem =)!